# SQL query returning doubled value

Tags: mysql, sql

The following SQL query is generating doubled-up `netincome`:

```
lead.leadId,
    sum(ifnull(applicantEmployment.netIncome,0)),
   sum(ifnull(applicantIncome.amount,0))
FROM
  lead LEFT OUTER JOIN applicant ON (lead.leadId=applicant.leadId  AND  lead.deleted= 0  AND  applicant.deleted = 0)
   LEFT OUTER JOIN applicantEmployment ON (applicantEmployment.leadApplicantId=applicant.leadApplicantId  AND  applicant.deleted = 0  AND  applicantEmployment.deleted =0)
   LEFT OUTER JOIN applicantIncome ON (applicantIncome.leadApplicantId=applicant.leadApplicantId  AND  applicant.deleted = 0  AND  applicantIncome.deleted=0)
WHERE
  lead.leadId  =  800
GROUP BY
  lead.leadId, 
  applicant.leadApplicantId
```

The above query results in:

[image: query results]

However if you look at the below tables, `sum(ifnull(applicantEmployment.netIncome,0))` should be:

```
= 10310.31+23380
= 33690.31
```

but it's coming out as `44000.62` which is `10310.31+10310.31+23380`

Table value:

[image: tables]

So it doubled up netincome for applicant id 5339 which has 2 rows in applicant income table.

Is it any type of SQL trap?

Comment: SQL trap? no just correct realtional behaviour. You are summing each record from lead you fetch and you can fetch the very same record multiple times because of the joins (if there are multiples references of that said record in the joined tables). To avoid it you can move the logic from the join clause to the where clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is normal behavior of joins. Look on the table before `SUM` and `GROUP BY` and it will become more clear. You can solve it using different approaches. One of them is to use subqueries behind `SELECT`

```
SELECT
   lead.leadId, 
   applicant.leadApplicantId,
   (
      SELECT sum(ifnull(applicantEmployment.netIncome,0))
      FROM applicantEmployment
      WHERE (applicantEmployment.leadApplicantId=applicant.leadApplicantId  AND  applicant.deleted = 0  AND  applicantEmployment.deleted =0)
   ) netincomeSum,
   (
      SELECT sum(ifnull(applicantIncome.amount,0))
      FROM applicantEmployment 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN applicantIncome ON (applicantIncome.leadApplicantId=applicant.leadApplicantId  AND  applicant.deleted = 0  AND  applicantIncome.deleted=0)
      WHERE lead.leadId=applicant.leadId  AND  applicant.deleted = 0  
   ) incomeSum
FROM lead 
LEFT OUTER JOIN applicant ON (lead.leadId=applicant.leadId  AND  lead.deleted= 0  AND  applicant.deleted = 0)
WHERE lead.leadId  =  800 and lead.deleted= 0
```